# iOS Auto Layout - Impossible case?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I need to create a launch screen Storyboard with 3 views. The middle view must have a 4:3 ratio, the top view must occupying 30% of the remaining space and the lower view must occupy the rest of the space.

For example, when the view is 375 x 667...

Middle view: 375 x 4/3 = 500

Top view (667 - 500) * 30% = 50

Lower view: 667 - 500 - 50 = 117

I tried everything I can think of (including using a UIStackView) but can't find a way to make it work.

Is it possible? What would be the right way?

Many thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily do that with autolayout, as you rightly say, because the thing your first view should occupy 30% of is not a contiguous piece of space. You can do it by adding two invisible views, to measure the "remaining space" with the height of a single view that you can take 30% of, but it's not worth the trouble. Just implement your requirements in code directly in `layoutSubviews` or similar.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a launch screen storyboard so I can't code it. It seems I will need to try something with invisible view. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, You can archive this by using equal height constraint with proper multiplier. Following are the steps in your case:

- Add all 3 views with required size as per screen size.
- Set equal view hight constraint for first view to super view as bellow.
  (Multiplier is set by considering you are working on view with size 375 x 667. Change it as required.)

[image]

- Set top, left & right constraint as required to zero.
- Set equal view hight constraint for second view to super view as bellow.

[image]

- Add other missing constraints to second and bottom view.

You are done.

Comment: Unfortunately, the top view should be 30% of the remaining height (total height - 4:3 view height). Not 30% of the total height. Thank!

Answer (score 0):

To get the height of the remaining space, I added a hidden view at the top with a 4:3 ratio contraint and another hidden view below that occupies the rest of the space. I coud then use height constrains relative to that second hidden view to layout my views.